# Extract all ocurrences between delimiters being that they can appear more than one per line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, yaml

I have a document file.yaml that have something like placeholders to replace:

```
class: ##TOPIC##-area
  name: myClass
type: Class
secretKey: private-##SECRET_KEY##
```

so far I've used grep to get the values of placeholders

```
grep -P '(?<=##).*(?=##)' file.yaml
```

then, I had those values:

```
TOPIC
SECRET_KEY
```

now, we have to introduce new properties that can have more than one placeholder per line

```
class: ##TOPIC##-area
  name: myClass
type: Class
secretKey: private-##SECRET_KEY##-encoded-##SUFFIX_CODE##
```

hence, grep no longer worked because the output became:

```
TOPIC
SECRET_KEY##-encoded-##SUFFIX_CODE
```

but, I want to have

```
TOPIC
SECRET_KEY
SUFFIX_CODE
```

I accept all kinds of suggestions and ideas to solve that. thanks

**edit: the idea is to just get those placeholders, not replace them. sorry for the misunderstanding.**

Comment: in the first line of the question you mention these are *placeholders to replace* so, are you ultimately looking to replace these 'placeholders' and if so then perhaps you could update the question to include your entire operation since an answer for 'find these strings' won't necessarily be the same as the answer for 'replace these strings'

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: To follow up on @markp-fuso's comment - in case this is what you have in mind, calling a tool to find the strings and then calling a tool to replace them will certainly be the wrong approach vs calling a tool to find+replace them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With using GNU `awk`, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, setting RS(record separator) as `##` till next occurrence of `#` followed by 2 occurrences of `##`. Then simply printing matched lines only by removing the not needed `##` in outcome as per shown output samples.

```
awk -v RS='##[^#]*##' 'RT{print substr(RT,3,length(RT)-4)}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With any `awk`, please try following program. Simple explanation would be, using `match` function of `awk` to match regex `/##[^#]*##/`(explained in above first solution already); in a while loop to print all the matches found in each line.

```
awk '{while(match($0,/##[^#]*##/)){print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-4);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

If `Perl` is your option, would you please try:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 while /##(.+?)##/g' file.yaml
```

- `-l` option appends newline character to the output of `print`.
- `-ne` option is mostly similar to that of `sed`.
- `$1` refers to the capture group 1 of the regex.
- The `while /pattern/g` syntax enables the multiple matches in the same line.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use `grep`, try something like

```
grep -Eo "##[^#]*##" file.yaml | tr -d '#'
```

With `awk` you can have a multi-character separator, that looks easier:

```
awk -F'##' '{for (i=2; i<=NF;i+=2) {print $i}}' file.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead to exclude substrings that contain `##` in them from the match.

```
(?<=##)((?!##).)*(?=##)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ocqq8m/1)

Note that this will also return `-encoded-` since it's also between a pair of `##`. Normally you won't get overlapping matches, but lookarounds aren't considered part of the match, so they don't count as overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get that output, is because the `.*` is greedy. You can make it non greedy `.*?` instead.

If you only want to output the matches, you can add `-o` to grep.

```
grep -oP '(?<=##).*?(?=##)' file.yaml
```

Output

```
TOPIC
SECRET_KEY
-encoded-
SUFFIX_CODE
```

---

If you have only uppercase placeholders where there can be an underscore in between, you can make the pattern a bit more specific.

```
grep  -oP "##\K[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*(?=##)" file.yaml
```

- `##` Match literally
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far (Clear the current match buffer)
- `[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*` Match 1+ uppercase chars, optionally repeated by `_` and uppercase chars
- `(?=##)` Positive lookahead, assert `##` to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dkvg3E/1).

Output

```
TOPIC
SECRET_KEY
SUFFIX_CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

If sed is an option, you can try this solution:

```
sed '/##.*##/!d
     s/##/\
/
     s/.*\n//
     s/##/\
/
     P;D' file
```

or, a plain `bash` solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    while [[ $line = *'##'*'##'* ]]; do
        line=${line#*'##'}
        printf '%s\n' "${line%%'##'*}"
        line=${line#*'##'}
    done
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk` for multi-char RS, RT:

```
awk -v RS='##[[:upper:]_]+##' 'RT{gsub(/##/,"",RT);print RT}' file
TOPIC
SECRET_KEY
SUFFIX_CODE
```